# Getting evaluate data and cookies of data from nightmare request

Tags: node.js, nightmare

How can I make one request to get `document.title` and the `cookies` in one nightmare request?

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')

Nightmare()
    .goto('http://cnn.com')
    .evaluate(() => document.title)
    .end()
    .then(console.log)

Nightmare()
    .goto('http://cnn.com')
    .cookies.get()
    .end()
    .then(console.log)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const nightmare = Nightmare()

async function example () {
    const call = nightmare
        .goto('http://cnn.com')

    const title = await call
        .evaluate(() => document.title)

    const cookies = await call
        .cookies.get()

    await call.end()
    return {title, cookies}
}
```